# nodejs mssql only called once

Tags: sql-server, node.js, npm

I have a simple loop of the function in NodeJS that request from SQL Server database and return the record. I also use Microsoft SQL Server client for Node.js which is `MSSQL`. In the code below, I loop 5 times that call the same function and expected the result will be repeated 5 times. However, the printed result only show the last one.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
       getRecord();
}

var getRecord = function(param) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    sql.close();
    sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
        return pool.request()
        .query('select TOP 1 * from table')
    }).then(result => {
        sql.close();
        console.log( result);
        console.log(' param : ' + param);
        resolve(result.recordset);
    }, function (err) {
        sql.close();
        reject(err);
    });

})
}
```

Result:

```
{ recordsets: [ [ [Object] ] ],
  recordset:
   [ { ..],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 1 ] }
 param : 4
```

Please help me understand why the printed result only the last one.

Thank you.

Comment: This looks to me to just be a presentation problem, and not an issue with the logic; I'll bet that query is firing 5 times.  Maybe tell us what you are trying to do.

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous in nature, when you call `getRecord`,  first loop will close connection and open new connection, second loop close first loop connection and open new connection and so on

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet for **getRecord** is called Asynchronously, So end of the loop only have an access to execute query. That is why mysql is called once.

In order to call the function on every iteration, make your snippet asynchronous.

```
var getRecord = function (param) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        sql.close();
        sql.connect(config).then(pool => {
            return pool.request()
                .query('select TOP 1 * from table')
        }).then(result => {
            sql.close();
            console.log(result);
            console.log(' param : ' + param);
            resolve(result.recordset);
        }, function (err) {
            sql.close();
            reject(err);
        });

    })
}

async function processRecord() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        await getRecord();
    }
}

processRecord();
```